Добавление текста в пост через REST API на сайт WordPress
С помощью такого адреса:
http://example.com//wp-json/wp/v2/posts/14564/?content=test
Я могу заменить тот текст, который ранее был опубликован на сайте, как его не заменить, а продолжить, то есть дополнить?
